How to fix HP printer only printing blank page when trying to print from Android phone?
I have a HP 5520 connected via WiFi, I can print from a Windows PC, I can print from an iPhone, yet once I try printing from an Android phone (e.g. Samsung 10e, One Plus 9 Pro) all I get is one white page. The Android phones are on Android versions 13 to 14.
The Android phones can see the printer, I can also access the printer's internal server.
The phones have the apps HP Smart and the HP print  service plugin installed.
The only way it would print is to use the ePrint feature, which basically turns my home based printer into a cloud-printer and I find it unreasonable to send private data from an Android phone per email to HP servers. This may be a workaround for someone, but ia no option for me.
I tried factory resetting the printer, yet still: when printing from Android phones all I get is one blank page.
Is there any way I can fix that or is this a known bug?

Related but no duplicate as not random: https://superuser.com/questions/450054/hp-4015-printer-randomly-printing-blank-pages

There's similar bug reports on HP forums yet the provided help is absolute generic copy paste unhelpfulness: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Tablets-and-Mobile-Devices-Ready-Only/blank-page-when-printing-from-Android-device/td-p/7928548

From what I can find the HP 5520 supports AirPrint which is for Apple products. There may be Android apps which support sending via that protocol.

@MorrisonChang I am open to app suggestions, as the search is not looking great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417265/printing-from-android-over-airprint

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293975/printing-to-an-airprint-printer-from-android

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436250/64146 and I'm inclined to think that the holdup is the lack of a good open-source "Apple Raster Format (URF) encoder" which AirPrint devices use.
